# How to store extension settings in MediaWiki?

Tags: settings, mediawiki, storing-data

I looked up for some plugins and I found that most of them ask to create manually one more table in database, or store their settings in some file.

What is the best way? Thanks.

PS I really don't think that the client want to create anything manually in his DB.

**UPDATED**
For now I'm using Special Page with form on it, and store settings as serialized data in file.

Answer (score 0):

As the install manual says, having shell access to the server is a requirement.
There are workarounds but don't expect everything to work.

Comment: Care to list any workarounds? Your answer is quite wooly and vague, as it stands.

Comment: As vague as the question. The OP didn't explain why editing configuration file(s) or creating tables is a problem; having shell access and run update.php usually suffices.

Comment: You could maybe share your work around knowledge for any future visitors. Lets face it, this question was asked in November 2012; I doubt the OP is still hanging around waiting for an answer.

Comment: Well, like I said in UPDATED part of question, I write settings of my plugin into the file. But now I use not `serialize`, but `base64_encode` to prevent any surprises with punctuation. This is my answer for now.